How Do I add a background service for my Flutter application
I am making an application which has a countdown timer. The application's mission is logging location data and sending it to Firebase Firestore while the countdown timer counts down on background. How could I handle this mission? Now I am learning Kotlin lang.

How about using this package? https://pub.dev/packages/background_location

Wow, this package looks fire, but if I can't add any countdown timer, it would be useless. In addition when the timer stops I need to show an alarm page.

You can use flutter_background_service library.

Please provide more details. Your answer only contains a link that can be broken in the future. In that case, your answer offers nothing much of a value.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
